# Update-Tools Powercli Error when try update VMware in Powershell

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am trying to update VMware tools for a bunch of VMs by below command

```
Foreach($vm in $vms )
{ Get-VM $vm | Mount-Tools
  Get-VM $vm | Update-Tools -Noreboot
  Get-VM $vm | Dismount-Tools
```

But i am getting below error:

> The Operation of the entity VirtualMachine-vm-12573 with following
>   message:"Error Upgarding vmware Tools"

Answer (score 0):

If you're just updating tools, the `Mount` and `Dismount` commands should not be necessary.

Try the following:

```
Foreach($vm in $vms ) {Get-VM $vm | Update-Tools -Noreboot}
```